# Issue with scrollWidth always being 0 when using ellipsis property for tooltips

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, ellipsis

I'm trying to create a tooltip that shows the full text when content is truncated using the ellipsis property. However, I'm facing an issue where **`scrollWidth`** is always returning 0. Here's my JavaScript and CSS code

```
var LoggedAsTestingLongText = "longtestforchecktheellipsispropertytoshowtooltip@example.com";
replaceText(LoggedAs,LoggedAsTestingLongText);
var usernameDiv = document.querySelector(".elipsiss.username");
LoggedAs.title=LoggedAsTestingLongText;
if (LoggedAs.offsetWidth < LoggedAs.scrollWidth) {
    console.log(LoggedAs.offsetWidth + " offsetwidth");
    console.log(LoggedAs.scrollWidth + " scroll width");
    console.log("scroll width");
    LoggedAs.classList.add("tooltip");
}
usernameDiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    if (!LoggedAs.classList.contains("tooltip")) {
        LoggedAs.removeAttribute("title");
        console.log("mouse enter");
    }
});
```

```
.elipsiss.username{
    //display : block;
    max-width: 70%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip[title]:hover::before {
    content: attr(title);
    background-color: yellow; /* Just for testing */
    color: rgb(148, 0, 0);
}
```

I've applied the **`ellipsis`** property to an element with class **`.elipsiss.username`** and added a tooltip to show the full text when the content is truncated. However, I noticed that the **`scrollWidth`** property is always returning 0, preventing the tooltip from appearing as expected. I suspect there might be an issue with the timing of when the code is executed or some interaction with other CSS rules.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with **`scrollWidth`** returning 0 in this context? Are there any alternative methods or suggestions for achieving the desired tooltip behavior when using the ellipsis property?

Comment: I would recommend posting a [mcve]